# How do create a page from pagelayout using code in sharepoint 2013

Tags: page-layout, application-pages

I was wondering, what APIs are available if I'm writing a farm-based sharepoint solution, for sharepoint 2013.

Basically I read about this thing called Page Layouts, and they seem like page templates. I want to generate an instance of it through my own code, in C#, how is that possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Get the relevant Publishing web which contains `GetAvailablePageLayouts`, and find the one which you should use to create your page. See sample code:

```
PublishingWeb publishingWeb = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(web);    
string pageName = "YourCustomPageLayout.aspx";    
PageLayout[] pageLayouts = publishingWeb.GetAvailablePageLayouts();    
PageLayout currPageLayout = pageLayouts[0];    
PublishingPageCollection pages = publishingWeb.GetPublishingPages();    
PublishingPage newPage = pages.Add(pageName,currPageLayout);    
newPage.ListItem[FieldId.PublishingPageContent] = "This is test content";    
newPage.ListItem.Update();    
newPage.Update();    
newPage.CheckIn("This is just a comment");
```

Also check [this](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2010/09/17/create-publishing-pages-sharepoint-2010-programmatically/) example

**Update:**

You can use the `SPLimitedWebPartManager` object to get the Web Part whose property you want to edit.

```
using (SPLimitedWebPartManager webPartManager = site.GetLimitedWebPartManager("yourpage.aspx", PersonalizationScope.Shared))
webPartManager.WebParts[0].webpartProperty = "Some example";
// Save the changes to the Web Part.
webPartManager.SaveChanges(webPartManager.WebParts[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it looks like PublishingWeb isn't available in Sharepoint solutions projects? At least I can't even find the reference assembly to add to the project, is it only available in Apps?

Comment: You need to add a reference to `C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.dll`

Comment: Cool thanks, another question I have is. With the way I'm approaching it, I'm hoping to have a base page layout that has where all the webparts are structured, how do I dig out a web-part from inside the page layout to configure some properties on it, or replace a query that it's pointing to? Thanks

Comment: See my updated response

Comment: This is a great solution; one I've been using and it works great. One thing you _may_ want to add is to Publish the page as well `newPage.Publish("Comment");`. By far that's most annoying part of SharePoint Publishing Pages, the Check-In then Publish 1-2 punch. Don't know why they just can't offer a combo action. Has anyone found a better way to pick out a specific page layout other than LINQing the list to find it by name?